# Time out on sending to a server socket

Tags: android, tcp, timeout

```
 public void sendToServer(String fileToSend, String ip, int sendPort)
{
    int port = sendPort;
    String url = ip;
    File file = new File(fileToSend);
    String fileName = file.getName();

    Socket sock;
    try {
        sock = new Socket(url,port);

        //Send the file name
        OutputStream socketStream = sock.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutput objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socketStream);
        objectOutput.writeObject(fileName);

        //Send File
        byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)file.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
        os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
        fileSentOkay();
        os.flush();
        sock.close();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        hostNotFound();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        hostNotFound();
    }
}
```

When I try to send something to the server when the server isn't listening for the connection, the phone keeps attempting to send the file. As a result of this, my Android program will eventually force close.

How could I set a time out for this to happen? Would I have to use something like `setSoTimeout()` on the socket that is sending the data?

Answer (score 0):

First: Just in case: Don't do network stuff on the UI Thread. Bad Things will happen (tm)

Second: `setSoTimeout()` should give you a timeout in case the server accepts the connection, but does not reply (or in case there is no reply from the network at all). In case the connection is rejected the socket should fail significantly faster.

Edit: In case the constructor of the Socket class is already taking that long, try using the [`connect(SocketAddress, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress,%20int%29) method. Use [InetSocketAddress](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html) as parameter:

```
Socket s = new Socket(); 
s.connect(..., 1000);
```

Comment: I added sock.setSoTimeout(1000), but it did not appear to affect anything. If I tried to send a file to a non-existent IP, it would still force close after a period of time.

Comment: Could you provide a logcat of the error which leads to the force close?

Comment: Hey, I couldn't get the formatting to work on here so I pasted to this link the logcat file before it force closed: http://pastebin.com/PGSGE3cd

Comment: Note my first hint: Don't do network stuff on the UI Thread. I updated my post with information about timeout in the constructor of the Socket class.